# How to get an element to be on top of all other elements (like the options of a select element)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a custom component in Angular that is similar to the select element. The problem I am facing is that when the droplist of my component opens, other elements are drawn on top of it. The problem persists even when I modify the z-index because it's in a different stacking context. However, this does not seem to be a problem that the options in the select element face. That means there must be a way to have the droplist appear on top of all other elements. Placing it in the shadow dom does not seem to help.

Edit:
Here is an example of what I am talking about. I need the foo element to be rendered on top of Layer 2 despite the parent element having a lower z-index. Notice the droplist of the dropdown is rendered on top of other elements despite having a lower z-index. Basically, I am asking if there is a way to override the z-index stacking in the same way that the dropdown option does. (Because I am trying to make a custom drop down widget).

```
<select style="z-index:-1;">
    <option style="z-index:-1;">An Option</option>
</select>
<div style="z-index:-1;position:relative;">
    <div id="foo" style="z-index:100;"></div>
</div>
<p class="text">Layer 2</p>
```

https://codepen.io/Bhargysaur/pen/yLzMPPd

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to provide more information. Ideally, provide a functional demo in the form of a snippet using the editor.

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: Anyone have any idea?